# How to store nested object ActiveAndroid?

Tags: android, orm, activeandroid

I'm working with ActiveAndroid library, I have the following problem:
I have two classes for my database, `Person` and `PersonPhoto`. Every person has only one photo, and photo is only for one person.

This is my code:

```
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person extends Model {
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String name;
    @Column(name = "photo")
    public PersonPhoto photo ;

   public Person() {}
}

@Table(name = "PersonPhoto")
public class PersonPhoto extends Model {

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String name;
    @Column(name = "photo64Code")
    public String photo64Code;    

    public PersonPhoto() {}
}
```

In my activity I have two buttons one for make an random insert and the other one for make and a general retrieving.

Here is the code:

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
            Person p = new Person();
            PersonPhoto photo = new PersonPhoto();

            photo.setName("photo");
            photo.setPhoto64Code("011110");

            p.setNickName("user");
            p.setPassword("123");
            p.setName("user");
            p.setfLastName("usera");
            p.setsLastName("userb");
            p.setLoginStatus(1);
            p.setPhoto(photo);

            p.save();
            p.getPhoto().save();
     }
```

My other button calls this method:

```
private List<Person> getAll() {
    return new Select()
            .from(Person.class)
            .orderBy("id ASC")
            .execute();
}
```

I ran it with my debugger and I saw my list details, all is okay individually But in my Person object I don't have my photo reference. It's marked like a null.

I don't know how to insert a nested object with ActiveAndroid.

Thanks for reading